# Qual é a diferença entre a união de um array via operador soma e a função array_merge?

Tags: php, array

Para unirmos dois arrays em um novo `array` no PHP, podemos fazer através da função `array_merge` ou através do operador de soma (`+`).

No caso temos dois exemplos:

```
$a = ['stack' => 'overflow'];
$b = ['oveflow' => 'stack'];

$c = array_merge($a, $b); //

$d = $a + $b;


print_r($c); // Array ( [stack] => overflow [oveflow] => stack )

print_r($d); // Array ( [stack] => overflow [oveflow] => stack )
```

Quais são as principais diferenças entre essas duas formas de se unir os `arrays`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Considerando as arrays `$a` e `$b`, as diferenças no resultado de `array_merge($a, $b)` (fusão) e `$a + $b` (união) serão:

- Na fusão, os valores das chaves numéricas existentes em ambas serão mantidas no resultado (porém com chaves reindexadas). Na união, o resultado mantém o valor que estiver em `$a`, e o valor em `$b` é descartado.
- Na fusão, os valores das chaves textuais existentes em `$b` prevalecem sobre os valores em `$a`, se a mesma chave existir nas duas arrays. Já na união, prevalecem os valores das chaves em `$a`.
- Em ambas as operações, chaves numéricas existentes apenas em `$b` são incluídas no resultado, reindexadas quando necessário.

Exemplo (["emprestado" do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23930891/825789)):

```
$ar1 = [
   0  => '1-0',
  'a' => '1-a',
  'b' => '1-b'
];

$ar2 = [
   0  => '2-0',
   1  => '2-1',
  'b' => '2-b',
  'c' => '2-c'
];

print_r(array_merge($ar1,$ar2));
print_r($ar1+$ar2);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1-0
    [a] => 1-a
    [b] => 2-b
    [1] => 2-0
    [2] => 2-1
    [c] => 2-c
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1-0
    [a] => 1-a
    [b] => 1-b
    [1] => 2-1
    [c] => 2-c
)
```

<sup>http://ideone.com/mx7OOB</sup>

Comment: Continuo confuso com estas duas formas...

Comment: É porque elas são confusas mesmo :)

Comment: Foi mal, tinha esquecido de marcar com o "verdinho"

Answer (score 5):

No `array_merge`, as chaves iguais são alteradas; com o operador `+`, elas ficam intactas.

No exemplo da [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-merge.php), o `array_merge` de um array vazio e outro com `1 => "data"` retorna um array com `0 => "data"`, mas usando os mesmos arrays com o operador `+`, o resultado é um array com `1 => "data"`.