# Como combinar quatro ou mais arrays?

Tags: php, array

Gostaria de combinar quatro ou mais array's. Com dois array's, utilizo o `array_combine` e tenho o resultado esperado, já com quatro, não.

Qual função devo utilizar para combinar quatro array's?

Segue meu código:

HTML

```
<input type='text' id='nome' name='nome[]' />
<input type='text' id='email' name='email[]' />
<input type='text' id='idade' name='idade[]' />
<input type='text' id='altura' name='altura[]' />
```

PHP

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$idade = $_POST['idade'];
$altura = $_POST['altura'];
$merg = array_merge($nome,$email,$idade,$altura);
foreach($merg as ... ) //aqui que está a minha dificuldade
{
    echo $nome; 
    echo $email;    
    echo $idade;
    echo $altura;   
}
```

Comment: Os indices dos arrays são os mesmos? o problema é que estão sendo sobrescritos.

Comment: Podes explicar porque precisas de combinar os arrays? É por teres inputs com os mesmos campos para pessoas diferentes? Seria interessante perceber melhor a funcionalide que precisas.

Comment: No texto vc fala que usa array_combine e no exempo voce usa arrary merge e dentro do loop voce usa as variaveis diretamente, sem ser pelo vetor, poderia explicar qual o **resultado** que vc deseja obter com o script?

Comment: Desculpe Guilherme, é que percebi que o array_combine não combina mais de dois valores, por isso passei a testar com o array_merge.

Tenho um formulário, onde são adicionados pessoas dinamicamente com estes quatro campos.

Após efetuar POST no formulário, gostaria de receber o nome dessas pessoas em forma de tabela (claro que dentro do foreach ainda não organizei os dados para serem exibidos em tabela).

Comment: Dê uma olhada em [Qual é a diferença entre a união de um array via operador soma e a função array_merge?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52349/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-a-uni%C3%A3o-de-um-array-via-operador-soma-e-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para combinar estes dados você pode criar em array bidimensional:

```
$dados = array();
foreach($nome as $k => $value){
    $dados[$k]['nome'] = $value;
    $dados[$k]['email'] = $email[$k];
    $dados[$k]['idade'] = $idade[$k];
    $dados[$k]['altura'] = $altura[$k];
}

print_r($dados);
```

#### Out

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        'nome' => 'Guilherme',
        'email' => 'Guilherme@mail.com',
        'idade' => '22',
        'altura' => '1.80',
    )
)
```

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, a sua solução foi perfeita.