# Juntar dois arrays em um só com PHP

Tags: php, json, array

Tenho o seguinte PHP:

```php
<?php
$itens1= array("fruta1"=>"laranja", "fruta2"=>"morango");
$itens2= array("fruta3"=>"goiaba", "fruta4"=>"uva");
array_push($itens1, $itens2);
echo json_encode($itens1);
?>
```

Gostaria que ele retornasse:

```php
{"fruta1":"laranja","fruta2":"morango","fruta3":"goiaba","fruta4":"uva"}
```

Mas não está dando certo, quando eu executo o PHP ele retorna:

```php
{"fruta1":"laranja","fruta2":"morango","0":{"fruta3":"goiaba","fruta4":"uva"}}
```

Ou seja, tem um "0" ali e mais duas chaves.
Já pesquisei e tentei de várias formas mas não estou conseguindo o resultado desejado.

Desde já agradeço quem puder me ajudar.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é a diferença entre a união de um array via operador soma e a função array_merge?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52349/5878)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use o `array_merge`, o `array_push` trata `array` como uma pilha, e adiciona as variáveis passadas como argumentos no final do mesmo, por isso você acaba ficando com essa estrutura:

```
array(3) {
    ["fruta1"]=>
        string(7) "laranja"
    ["fruta2"]=>
        string(7) "morango"
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
        ["fruta3"]=>
            string(6) "goiaba"
        ["fruta4"]=>
            string(3) "uva"
    }
}
```

O `array_merge` irá combinar/fundir os elementos dos arrays:

```
<?php
    $itens1= array("fruta1"=>"laranja", "fruta2"=>"morango");
    $itens2= array("fruta3"=>"goiaba", "fruta4"=>"uva");
    echo json_encode(array_merge($itens1, $itens2));
?>
```

Outra forma mais manual de resolver seu problema mantendo as chaves associativas seria com um loop de leitura e atribuição:

```
<?php
    $itens1= array("fruta1"=>"laranja", "fruta2"=>"morango");
    $itens2= array("fruta3"=>"goiaba", "fruta4"=>"uva");
    foreach($itens2 as $key=>$item){
        $itens1[$key] = $item;
    }
    echo json_encode($itens1);
?>
```

Desta segunda maneira você poderia utilizar o `array_push`, porém perderia a chave associativa:

```
<?php
    $itens1= array("fruta1"=>"laranja", "fruta2"=>"morango");
    $itens2= array("fruta3"=>"goiaba", "fruta4"=>"uva");
    foreach($itens2 as $item){
        array_push($itens1, $item);
    }
    echo json_encode($itens1);

    /* Resultado array
    array(4) {
        ["fruta1"]=>
            string(7) "laranja"
        ["fruta2"]=>
            string(7) "morango"
        [0]=>
            string(6) "goiaba"
        [1]=>
            string(3) "uva"
    }
    Resultado json
    {"fruta1":"laranja","fruta2":"morango","0":"goiaba","1":"uva"}
    */ 
?>
```